# How do I create JSON without recursively adding data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, d3.js

I am feeding Splunk data into a D3 visualization.  The D3 treemap requires the JSON array that populates the treemap, to be pre-calculated.

The data from Splunk returns in a tabular format, the first tables contains Active Directory paths ("ou=firefox enabled, ou=laptops, ou=computers, dc=domain") a size that indicates the number of boxes in that OU (10) and a number used to determine the color depicted in the treemap, amongst others.

I have this working perfectly on a small set of data (less than 500 or so rows), but when I bump it up to include about 1500 lines of Splunk data (1500 rows in the returned data) the script forces the browser to close.  Below are the applicable parts of code.

```
var nodeTree = new DeviceCountsplunkRowsBuilder(myResults.data().rows, colorMap);
          nodeTree.setRootNode();
          nodeTree.parseOUsplunkRows();

          // clear the chart
          d3.select("#chart").selectAll("*").remove();

          TreeMap(nodeTree.rootNode);

// OU Device Count Parser Class
//
// Description:
//    Builds the TreeMap data structure from the OU device count query in Splunk
//    Takes an array of rows as input E.G. SearchResults.data().rows;

function DeviceCountsplunkRowsBuilder(splunkRows, colorMap) {

  this.splunkRows = splunkRows;  
  this.colorMap = colorMap;

  // sets the root node when constructing the OUsplunkRowsMapBuilder Class
  this.setRootNode = function() {

    // take the first OU String and split it by comma
    var ouParts = this.splunkRows[0][0].split(",");
     // grab the last item in the array which is the highest level DC
    this.rootNode = new Node(ouParts[ouParts.length - 1]);

  };

  this.parseOUsplunkRows = function() {
    console.log("second length" + " " + splunkRows.length);
    console.log("length" + " " + this.splunkRows.length);
    for(var i = 0; i<this.splunkRows.length; i++) {
     console.log("row: " + i + " " + splunkRows[i][0]);
     this.splitOUString(this.splunkRows[i]);
    }

  };

  this.splitOUString = function(ou) {

    var ouParts = ou[0].split(",");
    console.log("after split " + i + " " + ouParts);

    // Recurse through OU String backwards from highest to lowest level
    for(var i = ouParts.length - 2; i>-1; i--) {

      node = new Node(ouParts[i]);

      console.log("node is:  " + JSON.stringify(node));

      // set distinguished name
      node.dName = ouParts;

      // set the device count
      node.devCount = parseInt(ou[1]);

      // set the score
      node.score = parseFloat(ou[2]);

      // set name intersection
      node.nameIntersect = parseInt(ou[3], 10);

      // set value intersection
      node.valIntersect = parseInt(ou[4], 10);

      // set STIG Name
      node.stigName = ou[5];

      // pick the color using colorize function
      node.color = colorize(this.colorMap, ou[2]);

      /*
      if(ou[2] > 0.8) {
        node.setColor("green");
      } else if(ou[2] > 0.6) {
        node.setColor("yellow");
      } else {
        node.setColor("red");
      }
      */

      // If the node is at the bottom of the tree assign it a value
      if(i == 0) {
        // If the count isn't a number assign it a value of 0
        // This fixes some of the issues with messy data
        if(isNaN(ou[1])) {
          node.setValue(0);
        } else {
          node.setValue(parseInt(ou[1], 10));
        }
      }

      this.rootNode.addChildRecursive(ouParts[i+1], this.rootNode, node);
      //console.log(node);
      //console.log(i);

    }

  };

}

//*****************************
// Node Class
//*****************************

// Node Constructor
function Node(name) {
  this.name = name;


  // Add a child node
  this.addChild = function(node) {

    // if this is the first child construct the children array
    if(!this.hasChildren()) {
      this.children = new Array();
    }

    // only add the node as a child if it is not already a child
    if(!this.childExists(node)) {
      //console.log("adding node " + node.name);
      this.children.push(node);
    }

  };

  // returns true if the given node is in the list of children
  // returns false if the node is not in the list of children
  this.childExists = function(node) {

    var inChildren = false;

    for(var i = 0; i<this.children.length; i++) {

      if(this.children[i].name == node.name) {
        inChildren = true;
        break;
      }

    }

    return inChildren;

  };

  // Optionally set the size of the node
  this.setValue = function(value) {
    this.value = value;
  };


  this.setColor = function(color) {
    this.color = color;
  };


  // Determins whether the children array has been initialized
  // returns either true or false
  this.hasChildren = function() {

    var nodeHasChildren = true;

    if (typeof this.children === 'undefined') {
      nodeHasChildren = false;
    }

    return nodeHasChildren;

  };

  // returns the array of children Node objects
  this.getChildren = function() {
    return this.children;
  };

  this.getNodeByName = function(name, node) {

    var theNodeYouAreLookingFor = null;

    if(node.hasChildren()) {

      var children = node.getChildren();

      for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

        if(children[i].name == name) {
          //alert("Found: " + children[i].name);
          theNodeYouAreLookingFor = children[i];
          break;
        } else {

          // recursively call getNodeByName
          this.getNodeByName(name, children[i]);

        }

      }

    }

    return theNodeYouAreLookingFor;

  };

  this.addChildRecursive = function(name, node, child) {

    var success = false;

    if(this.name == name) {
      this.addChild(child);
    } else if(node.hasChildren()) {

      var children = node.getChildren();

      for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

        if(children[i].name == name) {
          //alert("found node" + name);
          success = true;
          children[i].addChild(child);
          console.log(children[i].name + " => " + child.name);
          break;
        } else {

          // recursively call getNodeByName
          this.addChildRecursive(name, children[i], child);

        }

      }

    }

    return success;

  };


}
```

Comment: what do you mean "forces the browser to close"?  Are you saying the script hangs the browser or just does not return anything?

Comment: The scripts hangs the browser.. I would assume because of the recursion.